# Newton's Law of Cooling: find the air temperature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At noon, a roast is removed from the oven where its temp. was $170^\circ F$  and is placed in a room where it takes 1 hr for it to cool to $125^\circ F.$ If the roast is ready to be served at 2:00 pm when its temp. reaches $100^\circ F,$ what is the air temp. in the room?

#### Progress

I have the formula $T(t)=T_e+Ae^{kt}$. I know that the at $t=0$ is $T= 170$ then at $t=1$, $T=125$ and at  $t=2$ $T=100$ so I guess I'm trying to find $T_e$, $A$, and $K$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the formula for Newton's Law, and what values have you been given that you can put into it?

Comment: I have the formula T(t)=Te+Ae^(kt). I know that the at t=0 is T= 170 then at t=1 T=125 anf t=2 T=100 so I guess im trying to find Te, A, and K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let the room temperature be $T_0^\circ F.$  newtons law of cooling says 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left( T - T_0 \right) = -k(T-T_0) \tag 1$$ and we are given the following:

(a) $T(0) = 170,$

(b) $T(1) = 125$

(c)  $T(2) = 100$

the solution of $(1)$ is $$T - T_0 = Ce^{-kt} $$ usin the two data, gives us 
$$170-T_0 = C, 125 - T_0 = Ce^{-k}, 100 - T_0 = Ce^{-2k} $$

here is one way solve for $T_0.$

$$e^{-k} = \frac{125-T_0}{170 -T_0} = \frac{100-T_0}{125-T_0} \to170 \times 100 -270T_0 = 125^2-250T_0$$ therefore $$T_0 =\frac{17000-125^2}{20} = 68.75^\circ F  $$